# making UIPickerView from core data objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a Core Data entity Teacher, and I am trying to show all attributes(firstName, middleName, lastName) in a UIPickerVIew, so I am taking objects for more data:

```
- (NSArray *)takeTeacherForSubject {

    managedObjectContext = [AppDelegate sharedDelegate].managedObjectContext;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

    NSEntityDescription *description = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Teacher" inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext]; [request setEntity:description];

    NSError *requestError = nil;

    teacherForSubjectArray = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&requestError] mutableCopy];

    if (requestError) { NSLog(@"%@" , [requestError localizedDescription]); } return teacherForSubjectArray; 
    }
```

Methods from UIPickerDataSource:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
    (UIPickerView *)pickerView {
     return 1;
    }
- (int)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
        return [teacherForSubjectArray count];
    }
```

Making NSMutableArray of strings, from array of NSManagedObjects:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)makingDict {

    int count = [teacherForSubjectArray count];
    teacherStringsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];
    for (Teacher* object in teacherForSubjectArray)
    {
        teacher = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", object.firstName, object.middleName, object.lastName];
        [teacherStringsArray addObject:teacher];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", teacherStringsArray);
    return teacherStringsArray;
}
```

Making NSArray and show it:

```
    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{ NSArray
*array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:teacherStringsArray]; return [array objectAtIndex:row];
        }
```

but nothing goes into the screen. What's the problem? Maybe someone knows better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the teacher objects in your teacherForSubjectArray, there's no need for the method makingDict, or for creating a new array in titleForRow. You only need to extract the data from your teacher object in titleForRow,

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{ NSArray
    Teacher *teacher = teacherForSubjectArray[row];
    NSString *teacherName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", teacher.firstName, teacher.middleName, teacher.lastName];
    return teacherName;
}
```

By the way, you can use one line of code instead of three to create your request (I see a lot of people using these three lines, don't know why). Instead of this,

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *description = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Teacher" inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext]; 
[request setEntity:description];
```

You can use this,

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Teacher"];
```

Comment: i don't know why, but i tried to do the same, but it didn't work, so i did like this, some kind of insane. Thank you for explanation, it helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

From first glance, your code appears to be accurate.

Have you checked that the code is actually being called? Try adding an NSLog statement in your `numberOfComponentsInPickerView:` to make sure that method is actually being called. If it is not, then you need to set your `delegate` and `dataSource` of the `UIPickerView` so it knows where to get it's information from.

```
[myPickerView setDelegate:self];
[myPickerView setDataSource:self];
```

If you don't have these set, then the delegate methods will not be called and the `UIPickerView` will appear blank/empty.